# Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List

Tags: java, generics

```
SqlOutParameter out = new SqlOutParameter("out_refcursor",OracleTypes.CURSOR
                                           ,new StudentRowMapper());
```

// some code..

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = createMapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("in_studentid","101"); 

Map<String, Object> result = simpleJdbcCall.execute(parameters);
List<Student> students = (List<Student>) result.get("out_refcursor"); // here I get a warning
```

Definition of `execute()` method:

```
Map<String, Object> org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall.execute(SqlParameterSource parameterSource)
```

"Execute the stored procedure and return a map of output params, keyed by name as in parameter declarations.."

The warning on the above line :  `List<Student> students = (List<Student>) result.get("out_refcursor");` is:

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to List

I understand it is only a compile time warning, and Off course I can do a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to suppress it.

**Question:** But how do I properly cast it?

1. One way I tried out is

   ```
   List<Student> students = castObject( result.get("out_refcursor"));

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       private static <T extends List<?>> T castObject(Object obj){
       return (T)obj;
   }
   ```

Still I had to put `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in the `castObject()` method. And I don't know if this is correct way of doing.

2. Second way I tried is,

   ```
   List<?> students = castObject( result.get("out_refcursor"));

   Student student = (Student)students.get(0);

   private static <T extends List<?>> List<?> castObject(Object obj){
         if(obj instanceof List<?>) {
              return (List<Student>)obj;
         }
         return null;
    }
   ```

Any suggestions/advice are welcome.

Comment: If you know that the returned value is a `List<Student>`, you're fine.

Comment: The first way is fine if you know it will always return List<Student> if you aren't sure what it will return you should use your third approach...

Comment: I know it will always return `List<Student>`, So it is clean coding to put @SupressWarnings("unchecked") in that case? The third approach will avoid the warning too, but I felt too much code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second solution won't help (due to [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)), and will cause other problems too so probably not a good idea.

The first method will probably work in practice, but is a bit dodgy really. There's a subtle (but huge) difference between *sub-classing Generic types* and *subclassing their parameters* in Java - i.e. `ArrayList<Integer>` is not a subclass of `ArrayList<Object>`, but `ArrayList<String>` is a sub-type of `Collection<String>`: see [a more fun example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/). More formal Computer Sciencey background in [Wikipedia entry on Covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Generic_types).

So, IMO you should keep the casting there, keep the (necessary) annotation, and catch the `ClassCastException` to make sure that the exceptional (hence the name) cases are covered.

Comment: Thank you for all those references. But how can I keep it as `List<Object>` because `result.get("out_refcursor")` returns an `Object` not a list of objects

Comment: Oh right, misunderstood that, sorry. I think then you might as well cast it immediately to the `List<Student>` and keep the annotation on the call directly (with a comment on why it's safe, perhaps), as the other methods don't make it much safer, or remove warnings. If you want, you can always catch the `ClassCastException` and handle _that_ actual error situation...

Answer (score 10):

Some thing like that could work, as long as you know the class name of the element of the `List`. One issue here, the hard coded `ArrayList` instantiation.

```
public static <T> List<T> castList(Object obj, Class<T> clazz)
{
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    if(obj instanceof List<?>)
    {
        for (Object o : (List<?>) obj)
        {
            result.add(clazz.cast(o));
        }
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage :

```
List<Student> students = castList(result.get("out_refcursor"), Student.class);
```

Comment: +1 for that generic `castList()` for my understanding

Answer (score 1):

With streams you can cast each element in the list into the target type in one line :-

```
List<Student> students = ((List<?>)result.get("out_refcursor")).stream().map(Student.class::cast).toList();
```