# Unchecked cast from Object to List

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to extend a solution to the problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976978/type-safety-unchecked-cast-from-object-to-list).

The castList method shared there works greats for non-generic types.

```
public static <T> List<T> castList(Object obj, Class<T> clazz)
{
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    if(obj instanceof List<?>)
    {
        for (Object o : (List<?>) obj)
        {
            result.add(clazz.cast(o));
        }
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The issue we are having is trying to use this same idea when the return type is not something simple like a list of strings, but when the list is itself of another generic, like a list of maps.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) out.get("o_cursor");
```

Trying to use castList as follows produces type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Map> to List<Map<String, Object>>.  Is there a way to extend castList to do this?

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = castList(out.get("o_cursor"), Map.class);
```

I attempted a modified version specific to lists of maps, but still get an error "The method castMapList(Object, Class<Map<K,V>>) is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Object, Class<Map>)" which seems like a different flavor of the same error.

```
public static <K, V> List<Map<K, V>> castMapList(Object object, Class<Map<K, V>> clazz) {        
    if (object instanceof List<?>) {
        List <Map<K, V>> result = new ArrayList<Map<K, V>>();

        for (Object o: (List<?>) object) {
            result.add(clazz.cast(o));
        }

        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of erasure, there is:

1. No way to have a `Class<Map<K, V>>`.
2. No built-in way to check at run-time that every particular `Map` has some particular `K` and `V`.

That is:

1. As you found out, every generic class has a corresponding raw type `Class` object, e.g. `Map.class` is a `Class<Map>`.
2. Something like `obj instanceof Map<K, V>` is a compiler error and `Class` objects do not check generic arguments with e.g. `isInstance` and `cast`.

Point-being, you can't validate generics at run-time without some extra work.

You can still program around it, depending on what you're doing. So for example, one simple way is just to rebuild each `Map`, the same way you rebuild the `List`:

```
static <K, V> List<Map<K, V>> castMapList(
        Object obj, Class<K> keyType, Class<V> valueType) {
    if (obj instanceof List<?>) {
        List<Map<K, V>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object element : (List<?>) obj) {
            if (element instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
                Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();

                for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : (Map<?, ?>) element) {
                    map.put(keyType.cast(entry.getKey()),
                            valueType.cast(entry.getValue());
                }

                result.add(map);
            } else {
                // do something that you want?
                // personally I would throw ClassCastExceptions
                // but you seem to be returning null
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also, for example, it looks kind of like you seem to be doing some sort of deserialization, and you can bake the `Class` right in to the `Map` that gets serialized:

```
public class MyCheckedMap<K, V>
extends SomeMapImplementation<K, V>
implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final Class<K> keyType;
    private final Class<V> valueType;

    public MyCheckedMap(Class<K> keyType, Class<V> valueType) {
        this.keyType = Objects.requireNonNull(keyType);
        this.valueType = Objects.requireNonNull(valueType);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <K, V> MyCheckedMap<K, V> cast(
            Object obj, Class<K> keyType, Class<V> valueType) {
        if (!(obj instanceof MyCheckedMap<?, ?>))
            throw new ClassCastException(obj.getClass().toString());

        MyCheckedMap<?, ?> map = (MyCheckedMap<?, ?>) obj;
        validate(keyType, map.keyType);
        validate(valueType, map.valueType);

        return (MyCheckedMap<K, V>) obj;
    }

    private static void validate(Class<?> lhs, Class<?> rhs) {
        if (lhs == rhs)
            return;
        throw new ClassCastException(String.format("%s != %s", lhs, rhs));
    }
}
```

You have to write some boiler-plate code for each `List`, `Map`, etc., but probably not much more than you seem to be doing.

There are also some other ways to approach this sort of problem, like Neal Gafter's [Super Type Tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) and Guava's [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html), which is a derivative of Neal Gafter's idea. These essentially use reflection to achieve something like `MyCheckedMap`.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  This was extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether or not having unchecked warnings is an issue for you or not. For the map, you could do the following:

```
public <K, V> List<Map<K, V>> castMapList(Object object, Class<K> class1, Class<V> class2) {
    if (object instanceof List<?>) {
        List<Map<K, V>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map<K, V> o : (List<Map<K, V>>) object) { //Unchecked cast
            result.add(o);
        }

        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

or

```
for (Object o : (List<?>) object) {
    if (o instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
        result.add((Map<K, V>) o); //Unchecked cast
    }
}
```

I don't think having a suppress warning is the worst case for you, since even in the [cast method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)) from `Class.java`, they do it. You must be sure that the list contains maps though.

Comment: *"I don't think having a suppress warning is the worst case for you, since even in the cast method from Class.java, they do it."* That isn't good reasoning, because `cast` uses `isInstance` to prove that the unchecked cast is correct. `isInstance` can't validate generic arguments (i.e. it can only check `Map`, not `<K, V>`, which is why there is only e.g. a `Class<Map>`) so you're comparing apples to oranges. If we're doing full-on unchecked casting, then we might as well just cast the whole result of OP's `out.get` like `(List<Map<String, Object>>) out.get("o_cursor")`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.  Thanks again!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class CastUtility {

    public static <T> List<T> castList(Object object, Class<T> clazz) {
        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (object instanceof List<?>) {
            List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();

            for (Object o : (List<?>) object) {
                result.add(clazz.cast(o));
            }

            return result;
        }

        throw new ClassCastException();
    }

    public static <K, V> Map<K, V> castMap(Object object, Class<K> keyType,
            Class<V> valueType) {

        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (object instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
            Map<K, V> result = new HashMap<K, V>();

            for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : ((Map<?, ?>) object).entrySet()) {
                result.put(keyType.cast(entry.getKey()),
                        valueType.cast(entry.getValue()));
            }

            return result;
        }

        throw new ClassCastException();
    }

    public static <K, V> List<Map<K, V>> castMapList(Object object,
            Class<K> keyType, Class<V> valueType) {

        if (object == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (object instanceof List<?>) {
            List<Map<K, V>> result = new ArrayList<Map<K, V>>();

            for (Object o : (List<?>) object) {
                result.add(castMap(o, keyType, valueType));
            }

            return result;
        }

        throw new ClassCastException();
    }
}
```